# Are these two statements logically equivalent?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

Are the statements $D \Rightarrow H \vee S$ and $(D \Rightarrow H) \vee (D \Rightarrow S)$ logically equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes they are because the first statement is false only when D is true and both H and S are false. The same holds for the second statement. Thus they both have same truth values hence equivalent.